# How to apply label on polygon on stroke (border) using leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have this code where currently I am applying label to polygon on center, but I want them to appear on border of polygon instead of center. I am not able to get it done. Please help.

```
L.geoJson(geoJsonData, {
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    var label = L.marker(layer.getBounds().getCenter(), {
      icon: L.divIcon({
        className: 'label',
        html: feature.properties.NAME,
        iconSize: [100, 40]
      })
    }).addTo(map);
  }
);
```

Comment: You are calling `layer.getBounds().getCenter()` and placing your marker at that point.  That's why they're at the center.  where on the border do you want it exactly?  You need to specify the latlng

Comment: https://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.TextPath/